# Replace comma (,) with dot (.) in SQL and Float Datatype

Tags: sql, replace

I created a Table with numeric values like 9,35 or 10,5 in it. The Datatype is `float`. The table looks like this in the short version:

```
Currency | Euro | 2018 |
USD      | 1    | 9,35 |
```

Now I want to update my table and replace all komma (,) with a dot (.)

I tried it with this code:

```sql
update dbo.[Table]
set [2018] = replace([2018], ',','.')
```

It says that 24 Rows are affected but when I Update my table it changed nothing.
If I use this code:

```
select replace ([2018],',','.') from dbo.[Table]
```

Then it works fine but it don't update my table...

Comment: do not touch decimal separator. It is fixed. If you need to manipulate it for presentation, do it in your SELECT -query

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products, what RDBMS are you *really* using. As for your question, however, this is something for your presentation layer. Your column `2018`, doesn't have any commas or dots in it, it's stored as a binary value; how that value is displaced is *completely* up to the application, not the RDBMS.

Comment: Side note, `float` is a **terrible** choice of data type for something that appears to be a monetary value. Base 2 numbers and money do *not* mix well.

Comment: *24 Rows are affected* - the message is irrespective of what `replace` actually does, all 24 rows qualified as you have no `where` criteria; `replace` works on strings.

Comment: https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: thanks for the comments. the decimal number should be an exchange rate so that´s why I used the float data type.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to change all values in the Column 2018. At the moment the values have a comma (for example the 9,35) and I want to replace that comma with a dot. I also want to update my table with the code

Answer (score 0):

Numeric columns do not contain a separator - they use a separator when the data is *displayed*. The SQL server was probably set up with a culture that uses commas instead of decimals when it *displays* data. The coma is not stored with the value.

But, all you need to do is specify the format when you *display* the data, meaning in a report, form, app, whatever. *That's* where you specify how to format the values.

I would not format the data in the actual SQL query (e.g. converting the data to a string and specifying the format), since it makes it harder to do aggregations and other numeric operations on the client, and takes up more space in memory (which may not be a problem until you get to a massive scale).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, the server uses commas but I need to display it in decimals. I still have to figure out how to display it...

Comment: but where are you displaying it now that you see commas?  Just in a query tool? Where do you ultimately intend to display it?